# How to sort a Map by its value in dart?

Tags: dart

I want to sort a `Map<String,int>` by values.

```
{'201': 4, '2017CS197': 2, '2017CS300': 6, '202': 4, '205': 3, '206': 3, '207': 5}
```

this is my map.

after i want to get result as {'2017CS300': 6,'207':5,'202':4,'201':4,'206':3,'205':3,'2017CS197':2}

Thank You!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The default map class is insertion-ordered on the keys.
The easiest approach is to just create a new map with the same entries, added in the order you want.
First, let's find the order you want:

```
var sortedEntries = map.entries.toList()..sort((e1, e2) {
  var diff = e2.value.compareTo(e1.value);
  if (diff == 0) diff = e2.key.compareTo(e1.key);
  return diff;
});
```

(This assumes that your keys and values are all `Comparable`, otherwise you need to figure out how to compare them yourself. In this particular case, where keys are `String`s and values are `int`s, it's only `null` keys or values that may be incomparable).

This orders the entries in reverse value order, and for equal values, in reverse key order.

You can then create a new map from those entries:

```
var newMap = Map<String, int>.fromEntries(sortedEntries);
```

or you can modify the existing map by removing the old entries and adding the new:

```
map..clear()..addEntries(sortedEntries)
```

or

```
for (var entry in sortedEntries) {
  map..remove(entry.key)..[entry.key] = entry.value;
}
```

There is no functionality on the map class itself to order its entries.

Comment: Your code is not a fail safe. What will happen if the map will contain the value with `null` value? Yes. your code, in this case, will fail.

Comment: Correct. As stated, I assumed the values were `Comparable`, which `null` is not. If they are not `Comparable`, you will have to figure out how you want to compare them.

Answer (score 13):

To **sort a map by its value in ascending order** in Dart :

```
Map<String, int> map = {'one': 10, 'two': 5, 'three': 7, 'four': 0};

var mapEntries = map.entries.toList()
  ..sort((a, b) => a.value.compareTo(b.value));

map
  ..clear()
  ..addEntries(mapEntries);

print(map); // Must print: {four: 0, two: 5, three: 7, one: 10}
```

Comment: For descending order https://stackoverflow.com/a/58205412/12695188

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you could use `SortedMap` from [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/sortedmap):

> Unlike `SplayTreeMap` the objects can be ordered on both key and value or a combination of both.

Comment: it gives an error.
The argument type '(Pair<dynamic, dynamic>, Pair<dynamic, dynamic>) → int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Ordering'

Answer (score 0):

The official [recomendaton](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_for_elements_to_map_fromIterable.html) is to use 'for' elements when building maps from iterables:

```
var temp = {'201': 4, '2017CS197': 2, '2017CS300': 6, '202': 4, '205': 3, '206': 3, '207': 5};  

final sortedInReverse = temp.entries.toList()..sort((a, b)=> b.value.compareTo(a.value));
temp = {for (var entry in sortedInReverse) entry.key: entry.value};
```