# How to sort a length of int from a doccumentSnapshot in a listview.builder Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have already get the snapShot of array and count it using length. And displayed it. But I want to reorder it from much to lower in a listview.builder. How can I achieve that?

Backed structure
[image]

Code so far

```
    //I forgot to mention 
    //This is the usersCommentId from the snapShot of StreamBuilder on top of the widget tree
         final usersComment = snapshot.data?['usersComment'];
    
                           ListView.builder(
                                      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                      itemCount: usersComment.length,
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        return StreamBuilder(
                                            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                .collection("usersComment")
  //I tried filtered it here But that doesn’t work
                                                .where(usersComment[index])
                                                .snapshots(),
                                            builder: (context,
                                                AsyncSnapshot<
                                                        QuerySnapshot<
                                                            Map<String, dynamic>>>
                                                    snapshot) {
                                              final userComments = snapshot.data!.docs
                                                ..sort((a, b) => ((b.data()['vote']
                                                                as List<dynamic>?)
                                                            ?.length ??
                                                        0)
                                                    .compareTo((a.data()['vote']
                                                                as List<dynamic>?)
                                                            ?.length ??
                                                        0));
        
                                              final comment = userComments[index];
                                              final countVote = (comment.data()['vote']
                                                          as List<dynamic>?)
                                                      ?.length ??
                                                  0;
                                              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                                return Container();
                                              }
                                              return Text(
                                                countVote.toString(),
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                                              );
                                            });
                                      }),
```

Comment: Please share the collection structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already taken all List of `userComments`, I have a suggestion to make it with in single Stream query as following

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("usersComment").snapshots(),
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
            snapshot) {
          final userComments = snapshot.data!.docs..sort((a, b) => ((b.data()['vote'] as List<String>?)?.length ?? 0).compareTo((a.data()['vote'] as List<String>?)?.length?? 0));
          ListView.builder(
              itemCount: userComments.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                final comment = userComments[index];
                final countVote = (comment.data()['vote'] as List<String>?)?.length ?? 0;
                return Text(
                  countVote.toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 9),
                );
              });
        });
```

If you want to filter the `userComments`, then `stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection("usersComment").where(%your condition%).snapshots()`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. But I still have problem with filtering the userComments like the code above(Updated). But its still getting the ['vote'] of the entire collection and I don’t want that. So if you have any idea Plz help

Comment: If you want to filter, then your collection should have more details about how you want to filter, eg. `createdBy`, `accepted`, `postId` and so on. If this user comment is for post, then You will have postId from, and query will be `where('postId', isEqualTo: postId)`

Comment: I don’t quite get it. Can you maybe try update your code?

Comment: You may have to update the collection for this.

Answer (score 1):

1. take out the listview.
2. return listView inside the stream builder.
3. return everything in the collection (not each doc).
4. add all the votes in one list inside your stream builder.
5. sort the list and display using the ListView that is inside the stream

[how to sort in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58205412/11948079)